# Navigation Between Two View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have two View Controllers. in `mainViewController` there is `TabBarButton` when it clicked user goes to `1stViewController` and there is `UIButton` when it has clicked  user goes to `2ndViewController`.

before making my `2ndViewController` everything worked fine. but after i add `segue` function in my program i got error.

`could not cast value of type 'Calculator.1stViewController' (0x791a8) to 'Calculator.2ndViewController' (0x794c8).`

briefly my code is

```
  @IBAction func CalculateGpa(){
//Calucation Goes Here
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var AnotherName : 2ndViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! 2ndViewController
//Code here
}
```

UIButton Perform the segue and BarButton do nothing it just go to 1stView Controller. when i run the program and click BarButton im getting that above error.

its because prepareForSegue cant identify to which button it should perform right? how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "youridentifiername") {
      //your class name
        if let viewController: DealLandingViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DealLandingViewController {
            viewController.dealEntry = deal
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i update my code try this way to implement @axonlivelabs